# how to update build method in flutter without causing memory leak

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have this code which fetch data from `Firestore` and I have `setState` during build, but it keeps giving warnings about memory leak, however it's updated, but I need a way that avoid this warning, here is simple sample

```dart
bool isOne = false ;

//Stfl Widget
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack( //edit
children [
!isOne? Text('bool varible is false')
                     :  Text('bool varible is true')
 FutureBuilder(
       future: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users')
                  .doc('userId').get(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
           if(!snapshot.hasData){
                 return Text('');
              }else{ 
                  if(mounted) {
                      setState(() {
                      isOne = true ; // memory leak warning 
                          });
                   }
               }  
           return snapshot.data['name'];
```

also I tested this but the same warning

```dart
WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) => setState(() {}));
```

How can I handle that type of simple update during build tree without any memory leak causing?

Comment: Can you try with checking `FutureBuilder`'s snapshot state like waiting and errors?

Comment: You should use a state management package instead of calling setState repeatedly...See Riverpod here: https://riverpod.dev

Comment: Josteve i just read your link but i need example similar for mine above sing management package , and thanks if you did it in answer to vote it

Answer (score 1):

You have no need to set state. The `FutureBuilder` already rebuilds it's `build` method when the future finishes. You can just put this `FutureBuilder` around anything you want to update and use the `snapshot.data` to process.

Just as a bonus tip: `FutureBuilders` have a `initialData` parameter so you can use that and be sure that you never receive `null` values for example!

***Edit:***

Here is an example of how to do something like what you want to achieve using [Bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/bloc)'s Cubit base class. You could do something like this and create this cubit variable up in your widget tree and then pass it down wherever you want. Wherever you use this `NewWidget` and pass the same variable instance they will all update together.

```dart
final cubit = DocGetter(
  () {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc('userId').get()
  },
);

cubit.futureUpdate(
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc('userId').get(),
);

cubit.futureUpdateFunction(
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc('userId').get,
);

class NewWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const NewWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.child,
    required this.getter,
    this.childWhileEmpty,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Widget child;
  final Widget? childWhileEmpty;
  final DocGetter getter;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<Map>(
      initialData: cubit.state,
      stream: cubit.stream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        final map = snapshot.data!;
        if (map.isEmpty) {
          return childWhileEmpty ?? const SizedBox.shrink();
        } else {
          return child;
        }
      },
    );
  }
}

class DocGetter extends Cubit<Map> {
  DocGetter(Future<Map> Function() fn, {Map? initialState})
      : super(initialState ?? {}) {
    fn().then(update);
  }

  Future<void> futureUpdateFunction(Future<Map> Function() fn) async {
    final map = await fn();
    emit(map);
  }

  Future<void> futureUpdate(Future<Map> futureMap) async {
    final map = await futureMap;
    emit(map);
  }

  void update(Map newMap) => emit(newMap);
}
```

Comment: sorry it was my bad , please see my question again since i edit it , it is out Future widget

Comment: I can see that, but you only need to swap the Stack and the FutureBuilder, put the Stack inside and process it all inside the FutureBuilder

Comment: of course i can  do it , but it is just similar simple for big other code that cannot do this way

Comment: My suggestion then would be for you to look for other state management approaches. Something like Bloc or anything else where you can update a simple part of your code only and from far away in your widget tree. Would you like some better explanation into how to use Bloc (or Cubits that are simpler)? I could edit the comment to add that.

Comment: yes sure thanks

Comment: Updated the comment